# ModuleNotFoundError for import within the same package while using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

My project structure seems to be correct.

```
setup.py
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    main.py
    script1.py #import script2 
    script2.py
tests/
    test_script2.py
```

File `script1.py` imports `script2.py` using `'import script2'`.

I can run code without errors with following commands:

```
python mypackage
python mypackage/main.py
```

Unfortunately, when I try to execute tests using `pytest` or `python -m pytest` I get error that there's no module named `script2`(full message below). I installed my package in editable mode `pip install -e .`

I'm able to fix this by using imports with package name like `import mypackage.script2 as script2` but then, everyone who will clone my repository will have to install package with pip before running it. Otherwise there will error that `mypackage` is not found.

I'd like to be able to run this code without pip install and have the option to run each script file separately.
Could you suggest me alternative solution?

Repository: [pytest-imports-demo](https://github.com/lecho/pytest-imports-demo/tree/master)

Error message from pytest:

```
(venv) lecho:~/pytest-imports-demo$ pytest
================================================= test session starts ==================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.7, pytest-4.4.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0
rootdir: /home/lecho/pytest-imports-demo
collected 0 items / 1 errors                                                                                           

======================================================== ERRORS ========================================================
________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_script2.py ________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/lecho/pytest-imports-demo/tests/test_script2.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_script2.py:2: in <module>
    import mypackage.script1 as script1
mypackage/script1.py:1: in <module>
    import script2
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script2'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=============================================== 1 error in 0.05 seconds ================================================
```

Comment: Just a side-comment, I am not sure if you want to support Python 2 or not (feel free to disregard if the answer is yes), but the requirement for __init__.py files was dropped for Python3.

Comment: @jimf thanks for the tip. I wont to support only Python3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file `pytest-imports-demo/mypackage/script1.py` importing `script2` package should be done either:

```
from mypackage import script2
```

or

```
from . import script2
```

Also need to add empty `__init__.py` file to `pytest-imports-demo/tests/` directory.

As far as "I'd like to be able to run this code without pip install and have the option to run each script file separately." goes this can be done by making scripts executable and  providing full path to the scripts or putting path to the directory with these scripts into your $PATH environment variable. Alternatively it can be done via pip install (but additional settings are required in `setup.py` file).

But tests can be run without having to `pip install` your package.

I opened PR: https://github.com/lecho/pytest-imports-demo/pull/1